# My FCM notification does not expand when the app is in background

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, android-notifications

I am implementing **FCM** to push notifications, but I am trying to expand the notification when the content of the notification is big.
It cannot be implemented when the app is in background

here is my code

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_new_logo).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_stat_new_logo))
            .setContentTitle("SuezApp")
            .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(title))
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody()))
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    final NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle style = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle(notificationBuilder);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
```

How can I expand it when the app is in background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [Firebase 9.4 release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#9.4):

> Expanded gestures are now supported for messages, allowing the Android UI to display multiple lines when the body of a notification exceeds a single line.

Make sure you are using Firebase 9.4 or higher as your dependency.

Comment: Thanks a lot you save my day